# uuid decode in python

Tags: python

I was able to encode a string with uuid_3 but I can not figure out a way to decode it.

My code to encrypt:

```
new_id = uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to decrypt your `uuid`. `uuid3` [is based on an `md5` hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3), which is an irreversible hashing algorithm. A `uuid` really shouldn't be relied upon for encryption anyways, since they are just identifiers. There are encryption/decryption schemes designed for this such as foreign key encryption and symmetric key encryption, to name a few.